# AWK: how to sort column in awk script as part of a for loop

Tags: awk

I have the following awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
awk '
        BEGIN{
        FS=OFS="\t";
        printf "\n\n%33-s\t%20-s",
        "Description", "Amount"
        printf "\n-------------------------------------------------- \n";       
        } 
        {
        if ($3 > 0) {               
                a[$7] += $3;
                sa += $3;
        }
        else {
                b[$7] += $3;
                sb += $3;
        }        
        }
        END{
        print "INCOME" "\n";
        for (i in a) {                                        
                printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", i, a[i];
        }
        printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", "\nTOTAL INCOME", sa;
        print "\n""\n" "EXPENSES" "\n";
        for (j in b) {
                printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", j, b[j];        
        }
        printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", "\nTOTAL EXPENSES", sb;
        }
' "${@:--}"
```

This prints the following as expected after running ./report out.txt:

```
Description                         Amount              
-------------------------------------------------- 
INCOME

Client Income                        65855.52           
Other Income                         33496.21           
Refunds                              24072.49           
Transfers                            66445.38           
Rental Income                        74505.46           
Tax Refunds                          2200.16            
Salaries & Wages                     234198.04          
Interest                             4.07               

TOTAL INCOME                         500777.33          


EXPENSES

Business - Miscellaneous            -473.55             
Government                          -985.83             
Personal Expenditures               -89212.40           
Hiring & Rentals                    -3271.20            
Travel                              -24148.74           
Accounting & Legal                  -3091.20            
Bank – Charges                      -1106.87            
Motor Vehicle – Miscellaneous       -153.59             
Vehicle Miscellaneous               -70.00              
Capex                               -18186.76           
Food - Fast Food                    -3004.19            
Christian to Edorne                 -1018.88            
Business – Miscellaneous            -63.09              
Bank – Withdrawals                  -5720.00            
IT – Subscriptions                  -1077.95            
Property – Rent                     -60100.00           
Food – Groceries                    -65760.27           
Equipment Hiring                    -3325.00            
Property – Maintenance              -13956.72           
Transfers Overseas                  -27638.31           
Property – Bond                     -1800.00            
Business – Repairs & Maintenance    -1362.25            
Weed Spray Chemicals                -133.17             
Transport                           -218.40             
Motor Vehicle Expenses              -862.52             
Business – ACC                      -206.04             
Education                           -1515.04            
Office & Stationary                 -323.34             
Food – Liquor                       -405.55             
Petrol - Vehicle                    -10341.62           
Petrol - Equipment                  -823.12             
Transfers                           -211239.22          
Property - Maintenance              -10762.56           
Business – Storage                  -1659.50            
Motor Vehicle – Parking             -39.90              
Motor Vehicle – WOF                 -264.05             
IT – ISP                            -14706.36           
Tax                                 -11783.08           
Food – Fast Food                    -4410.23            
Electricity                         -6980.73            
Christian to Crewcut                -20.95              
Healthcare                          -7250.95            
Vehicle – Maintenance               -302.00             
Food – Eating Out                   -6209.95            
Business Services – Mail            -400.00             
Household                           -2190.58            
Edorne to Christian                 -4961.30            
Salaries & Wages                    -55634.21           
Miscellaneous                       -1788.81            
Insurance                           -2623.96            
Motor Vehicle – Maintenance         -4711.62            
Property – Body Corporate           -26736.16           
Principal & Interest                -12605.61           
Property – Rates                    -16336.82           

TOTAL EXPENSES                      -743974.15
```

My question is how can I sort the income and expense items in alphabetical order (first column)? I have tried to sort the first column by changing the for loop lines to

```
printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", i, a[i] | "sort -u";
printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", j, b[j] | "sort -u";
```

which does not work.
I am not really able to provide source data for security reasons and due to the vast amount of data. My hope is that someone can help me with this anyway as my question is rather general in nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU awk` you can [control array scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) via `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to sort arrays (by index or data) so that `for (index in array)` processes the array in the desired order.

Adding this to your `END` block processing would look like:

```
    END{

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"                 # sort array by index based on "string" data and in "ascending" order

    print "INCOME" "\n"
    for (j in a) {                                        
            printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", i, a[i];
    }
    printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", "\nTOTAL INCOME", sa;
    print "\n""\n" "EXPENSES" "\n"
    for (j in b) {
            printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", j, b[j];        
    }
    printf "%-33s\t%-20 .2f\n", "\nTOTAL EXPENSES", sb
    }
```

**NOTE:** once set the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` applies to all array references until either the end of the `awk` script or until a new `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` is applied

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find it easier to sort the date before running this script. You don't tell us where it's coming from but either specify sort column or pipe it through awk '{ print $3 $7}' | sort